# Ubuntu создание ярлыка в applications

Tags: linux, ubuntu, golang, jetbrains

Установил Goland при помощи Jetbrains Toolbox сделал ярлык в папке `/usr/share/applications` 
Запускаю наутилус с админа работает, с обычного пользователя нет и нет программы в Show Applications. Попытался дать `chmod 777` не помогло.
ОС Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: 1. какой ещё «админ»? 2. какой ещё «ярлык»? 3. что это вообще за действие такое «установил golang при помощи jetbrains toolbox» и как вы до него додумались? 4. есть подозрение, что речь про дистрибутив не gnu/linux, а ms/windows. вы не ошиблись в метках, заголовке и тексте вопроса?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/install-and-set-up-product.html#install-GoLand , тут и про Toolbox и про системы, в метках ТС не ошибся

Comment: Есть удобная гуишная утилита для создания лаунчеров - **menulibre**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

у меня была похожая проблема с созданием ярлыка.
Ярлык приложения это текстовый файл с примерно таким содержимым:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Besiege
Comment=
Exec=/home/anon/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/Besiege/Besiege.x86_64
Icon=/home/anon/Besiege/Besiege_Data/Resources/UnityPlayer.png
Path=/home/anon/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/Besiege
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=false
Categories=Application;Game;StrategyGame;
```

Твоя задача создать такой же файл с расширением .desktop, после в строку Exec указать путь до исполняемого файла или просто команду. В строку Icon указать изображение иконки. В строку Path указать рабочий каталог приложения, чаще всего та папка где оно находится.
Дальше переноси в папку `/usr/share/applications` для того чтобы каждый пользователь системы смог увидеть приложение в списке. Или переместить в ~/.local/share/applications/, это только для пользователя.
Права на файл такие:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 anon users  333 дек 24 15:56  besiege.desktop
```

Если буду вопросы, то пиши.

Comment: Отлично получилось